# Compressing images on opencv (imwrite). How to explicitly set the compression factor?

Tags: c++, image, graphics, vector, opencv

I was wondering if there is a way to easily specify the compression factor when compressing images on opencv without having to declare a dummy vector. If I declare a vector p (similar to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801054/opencv-cvsaveimage-jpeg-compression-factor)), but containing only 2 items, which is what imwrite takes, I can make the call:

```
vector<int> p(2);
p[0] = CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY;
p[1] = 50; // compression factor

imwrite("compressed.jpg", img, p);
```

The above works fine. However, I want to compress the same image with several compression factors in a loop. Is there  a way to explicitly pass the parameter to imwrite? Something like:

```
imwrite("compressed.jpg", img, {CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, factor}); // this doesn't work
```

Just as a side note, the function header is:

```
bool imwrite(const string& filename, const Mat& img, const vector<int>& params=vector<int>());
```

Thanks!

**Update:**
After activating C++0x, I can pass a vector explicitly defined inline to the function.

Comment: This is running on a VM with gcc version 4.5.2

Comment: If you enable C++0x support, you can say `std::vector<int>({1,2})` inline.

Comment: Yep, that was all it took ;) Thanks

Comment: Put your update in answer and mark as "answered".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested, activating C++0x allows me to pass a vector explicitly defined inline to the function. This solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<int> compression_params;
compression_params.push_back(IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
compression_params.push_back(30);
compression_params.push_back(IMWRITE_JPEG_PROGRESSIVE);
compression_params.push_back(1);
compression_params.push_back(IMWRITE_JPEG_OPTIMIZE);
compression_params.push_back(1);
compression_params.push_back(IMWRITE_JPEG_LUMA_QUALITY);
compression_params.push_back(30);
imwrite('sample.jpg', img, compression_params);
```