# How to write mp4 video file with H264 codec?

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg, codec

On OSX I can record from my webcam and write a video file with the following simple script:

```
import cv2
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object to save the video
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 25.0, (640, 480))

while True:
    try:
        (grabbed, frame) = camera.read()  # grab the current frame
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))  # resize the frame
        video_writer.write(frame)  # Write the video to the file system

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        camera.release()
        break
```

The resulting avi file is quite big though. I want a smaller file, preferably an mp4. So I changed the filename to `output.mp4` and the fourcc codec to `H264`. That writes a video file which works, but gives me the following error:

```
$ python write_video_file.py 
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x34363248/'H264' is not supported with codec id 28 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x00000021/'!???'
```

Since I thought I'm missing the H264 codec in ffmpeg I decided to uninstall ffmpeg and opencv and reinstall them again with H264 support. For this I used the following commands:

```
# First ffmpeg
brew install ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac --with-libvidstab --with-openh264 \
      --with-openjpeg  --with-openssl --with-tools --with-webp --with-x265 --with-zeromq
# then opencv3
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install opencv3 --with-contrib --with-ffmpeg --with-tbb
```

After this I ran the script again, using the following combinations:

- `output.mp4` with `H264`
- `output.mp4` with `X264`

Unfortunately I still get the OpenCV warnings/errors. The file is readable, but it still annoys me that I get these errors. Does anybody have any idea how I can make OpenCV write mp4 video file with the H264 codec?

All tips are welcome!

Comment: Did you try a restart?

Comment: @StavrosAvramidis - No, restarting didn't help

Comment: make sure you have ffdshow (both x32 and x64)

Comment: @StavrosAvramidis - Isn't `ffdshow` for decoding/showing files, instead of encoding/writing files?

Comment: yes ,but you never know

Comment: @StavrosAvramidis - `ffdshow` is windows software. I'm on OSX.

Comment: Here some posts you might take a look:
http://answers.opencv.org/question/120081/videowriter-recording-mp4-x264-opencv-31/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34024041/writing-x264-from-opencv-3-with-ffmpeg-on-linux

Answer (score 1):

I spent ages trying to find a list of video codecs on **macOS**, and finding which codecs work with which containers, and then if **QuickTime** can actually read the resulting files.

I can summarise my findings as follows:

```
.mov container and fourcc('m','p','4','v') work and QuickTime can read it
.mov container and fourcc('a','v','c','1') work and QuickTime can read it
.avi container and fourcc('F','M','P','4') works but QuickTime cannot read it without conversion
```

---

I did manage to write `h264` video in an `mp4` container, as you wanted, just not using OpenCV's **VideoWriter**  module. Instead I changed the code (mine happens to be C++) to just output raw `bgr24` format data - which is how OpenCV likes to store pixels anyway:

So the output of a frame of video stored in a `Mat` called `Frame`  becomes:

```
cout.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(Frame.data),width*height*3);
```

and then you pipe the output of your program into `ffmpeg` like this:

```
./yourProgram | ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -pixel_format bgr24 -video_size 1024x768 -i - -c:v h264 -pix_fmt yuv420p video.mp4
```

---

Yes, I know I have made some assumptions:

- that the data are CV8_UC3,
- that the sizes match in **OpenCV** and **ffmpeg**, and
- that there is no padding or mad stride in the **OpenCV** data,

but the basic technique works and you can adapt it for other sizes and situations.