# C++ OpenCV 3.4 / FFMPEG 3.4.1 VideoWriter and MP4 Output File Format

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg

I'm running on an ARM BeagleBone X-15 Debian machine with Linux Kernel 4.9.35-ti-r44. In my C++ ( Qt 5 ) application, I want to save my cv::Mat frames to an MP4 format video. I have libx264 installed and compiled from scratch both ffmpeg and OpenCv. I can successfully record and view video with MJPEG with the AVI video container type but not MP4. Whenever I try to write an MP4 video, I get run time errors of the form:

```
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x44495658/'XVID' is not supported with codec id 13 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x00000020/' ???'
```

I've tried various Google answers but none have worked.

Relevant code:

```
cv::Size frameSize = frame.size();

qDebug() << "Initializing Video Recording to save Video file here: " << destinationFileName;

std::string filename = destinationFileName.toStdString();
//int fcc =   CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G');
//int fcc =   CV_FOURCC('X','2','6','4');
int fcc = CV_FOURCC('X','V','I','D');
int fps =   1;
videoRecorder = new cv::VideoWriter(filename,fcc,fps,frameSize);

...

videoRecorder->write(frame);
```

I've downloaded and built the latest OpenCV 3.4 but the problem persists. 
How can I write to an MP4 File with OpenCV's video writer?

When I try the 'X','2','6','4' format I get the error:

```
    Initializing Video Recording to save Video file here:  "/tmp/Garage.mp4"
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x34363258/'X264' is not supported with codec id 28 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x31637661/'avc1'
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x81042020] Could not find a valid device
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x81042020] can't configure encoder
Could not open codec 'h264_v4l2m2m': Unspecified error
Starting
```

When I try the 'X','V','I','D' format I get the error:

```
Initializing Video Recording to save Video file here:  "/tmp/Garage.mp4"
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x44495658/'XVID' is not supported with codec id 13 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x7634706d/'mp4v'
Starting
```

When I try the 'M','P','E','G' format I get the error:

```
Initializing Video Recording to save Video file here:  "/tmp/Garage.mp4"
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x4745504d/'MPEG' is not supported with codec id 2 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x7634706d/'mp4v'
Starting
```

When I try the 'H','2','6','4' format I get the error:

```
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x34363248/'H264' is not supported with codec id 28 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x31637661/'avc1'
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x7fdde340] Could not find a valid device
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x7fdde340] can't configure encoder
Could not open codec 'h264_v4l2m2m': Unspecified error
Starting
```

When I try the 'M','P','4','V' format I get the error:

```
Initializing Video Recording to save Video file here:  "/tmp/Garage.mp4"
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x5634504d/'MP4V' is not supported with codec id 13 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x7634706d/'mp4v'
Starting
```

When I try the 'A','V','C','1' format I get the error:

```
Initializing Video Recording to save Video file here:  "/tmp/Garage.mp4"
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x31435641/'AVC1' is not supported with codec id 28 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x31637661/'avc1'
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x810f5f50] Could not find a valid device
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x810f5f50] can't configure encoder
Could not open codec 'h264_v4l2m2m': Unspecified error
Starting
```

When I try the 'D','I','V','X' format I get the error:

```
Initializing Video Recording to save Video file here:  "/tmp/Garage.mp4"
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x58564944/'DIVX' is not supported with codec id 13 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x7634706d/'mp4v'
Starting
```

When I try the 0x21 format I get the error:

```
Initializing Video Recording to save Video file here:  "/tmp/Garage.mp4"
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x00000021/'!???' is not found (format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)')'
Starting
```

Here is my complete class which shows all tried formats:

```
    #include "downloader.h"

Downloader::Downloader(QString url, QString destinationFile) : downloadUrl(url) , destinationFileName(destinationFile)
{

    didInitializeVideoWriter = false;

    qDebug() << "Initialized Downloader...";

}

Downloader::~Downloader() {

    videoRecorder->release();
    delete videoRecorder;

}

void Downloader::doDownload()
{
    networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    connect(networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
            this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

    networkManager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(downloadUrl)));
}

void Downloader::writeFrame(cv::Mat frame) {

    QMutexLocker locker(&videoFrameMutex);

    videoRecorder->write(frame);

}

void Downloader::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{

    if(reply->error())
    {
        qDebug() << "ERROR!";
        qDebug() << reply->errorString();
    }
    else
    {
        //qDebug() << reply->header(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader).toString();
        //qDebug() << reply->header(QNetworkRequest::LastModifiedHeader).toDateTime().toString();
        //qDebug() << reply->header(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader).toULongLong();
        qDebug() << reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
        qDebug() << reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpReasonPhraseAttribute).toString();

        QString tempFileName = destinationFileName;
        QString jpegTempFilename = QString("%1").arg(tempFileName.replace("mp4","jpeg"));

        qDebug() << "Overwriting: " << jpegTempFilename;
        QFile *file = new QFile(jpegTempFilename);
        if(file->open(QFile::WriteOnly))
        {
            file->write(reply->readAll());
            file->flush();
            file->close();
        }
        delete file;

        cv::Mat frame = imread(jpegTempFilename.toStdString(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR (>0) loads the image in the BGR format
        cv::cvtColor(frame,frame,CV_BGR2RGB);

        // Now lazy load the recorder
        if ( !didInitializeVideoWriter ) {

            cv::Size frameSize = frame.size();

            qDebug() << "Initializing Video Recording to save Video file here: " << destinationFileName;

            std::string filename = destinationFileName.toStdString();
            //int fcc =   CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G');
            int fcc =   CV_FOURCC('X','2','6','4');
            //int fcc = CV_FOURCC('X','V','I','D');
            //int fcc = CV_FOURCC('M','P','E','G');
            //int fcc = CV_FOURCC('H','2','6','4');
            //int fcc = CV_FOURCC('M','P','4','V');
            //int fcc = CV_FOURCC('A','V','C','1');
            //int fcc = CV_FOURCC('D','I','V','X');
            //int fcc = 0x21;
            //int fcc = 0x00000021;
            int fps =   1;
            videoRecorder = new cv::VideoWriter(filename,fcc,fps,frameSize);

            qDebug() << "Starting";
            frameCounter = 1;
            performanceTimer.start();

            didInitializeVideoWriter = true;

        }

        cv::putText(frame,"[REC]",cv::Point(50,50),5,1,cv::Scalar(0,0,225));

        QFuture<void> backgroundRun = QtConcurrent::run(this, &Downloader::writeFrame, frame);
        //backgroundRun.waitForFinished();

    }

    reply->deleteLater();

    qDebug() << "RequestTimer: " << performanceTimer.elapsed() << frameCounter;

    // Requests Again
    networkManager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(downloadUrl)));

    frameCounter++;

    performanceTimer.restart();


}
```

Update - I tried 'a','v','c','1' and unfortunately that also does not work:

```
Initializing Video Recording to save Video file here:  "/tmp/Garage.mp4"
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x810f6aa0] Could not find a valid device
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x810f6aa0] can't configure encoder
Could not open codec 'h264_v4l2m2m': Unspecified error

(qt-downloader:6234): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_make_from_uri: assertion 'gst_uri_is_valid (uri)' failed
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (GStreamer: cannot link elements
) in CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open, file /media/usb/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line 1635
VIDEOIO(cvCreateVideoWriter_GStreamer (filename, fourcc, fps, frameSize, is_color)): raised OpenCV exception:

/media/usb/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:1635: error: (-2) GStreamer: cannot link elements
 in function CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open
```

When I try the X264 FOURCC, the mp4 file is 48 bytes and never grows:

```
Initializing Video Recording to save Video file here:  "/tmp/Garage.mp4"
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x34363258/'X264' is not supported with codec id 27 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x31637661/'avc1'
```

Static Size:

```
debian@BeagleBoard-X15:/tmp$ ls -lrt Garage.*
-rw-r--r-- 1 debian debian     48 Dec 24 21:13 Garage.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 debian debian 100424 Dec 24 21:14 Garage.jpeg
debian@BeagleBoard-X15:/tmp$ hexdump Garage.mp4 
0000000 0000 2000 7466 7079 7369 6d6f 0000 0002
0000010 7369 6d6f 7369 326f 7661 3163 706d 3134
0000020 0000 0800 7266 6565 0000 0000 646d 7461
0000030
```

Here is my ffmpeg build conf:

```
debian@BeagleBoard-X15:/tmp$ ffmpeg -buildconf
ffmpeg version N-89524-g74f408cc8e Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18) 20170516
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-pthreads --enable-static --extra-cflags=-I./x264/include --extra-ldflags=-L./x264/lib --extra-libs=-ldl
  libavutil      56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
  libavcodec     58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavformat    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavdevice    58.  0.100 / 58.  0.100
  libavfilter     7.  7.100 /  7.  7.100
  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100

  configuration:
    --enable-gpl
    --enable-libx264
    --enable-pthreads
    --enable-static
    --extra-cflags=-I./x264/include
    --extra-ldflags=-L./x264/lib
    --extra-libs=-ldl
```

Comment: Can you try to encode video using ffmpeg command line (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MPEG-4)? Maybe ffmpeg on your machine is missing libxvid?

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I've made sure libxvid is installed. My make pro file includes both libx264 and libxvidecore ( LIBS += -lx264
LIBS += -lxvidcore ) . However, I still see the problem.

Comment: Do you link those libraries when building ffmpeg or just link them to your project?

Comment: installed them from apt-get after installing ffmpeg from apt-get as well - so maybe my ffmpeg doesn't have support! I'll try to compile it.

Comment: I recompiled FFMPEG 3.4.1 and OpenCV 3.4 and unfortunately none of the formats showed in my revised post work.

Comment: Since you are doing such a fine job of testing every option, you might as well try `FMP4` and `DIV3` ;-)

Comment: I would also recommend to test ffmpeg without opencv (using command line ffmpeg) to localize the issue

Comment: With libx264, it should be `'a','v','c','1'`

Comment: And see https://stackoverflow.com/q/34024041/5726027

Comment: @Mulvya - I tried avc1, but unfortunately I hit the same issue. Please see my revised post.

Comment: This is a different error. The tag has been accepted but ffmpeg is selecting a different (HW) encoder, not x264, because the v4l2 has higher priority. Can you explicitly set encoder to libx264 in OpenCV?

Comment: Share the full output of `ffmpeg -buildconf`

Comment: what is wrong with  fallback to mp4v? did you check the output video from this?

Comment: The fallback to mp4v doesn't work. The mp4 file is created by OpenCV but it is always a static 48 bytes and never grows. I've pasted the hexdump of the file ( just a header? ) above. I've also pasted my FFMPEG build conf in the post and it shows libx264.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with you, but running on MacOS. I solved it by re-installing X264 library to the latest version, and then re-install FFMPEG with `./configure --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-avresample --enable-shared` to link the new X264 to FFMPEG properly. Then, re-install OpenCV (I am using version 3.4.4) to link the new FFMPEG. When building the OpenCV, make sure that `WITH FFMPEG` is `ON` otherwise built-in OpenCV encoder will be used, which will give you more limited options.

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried ust in plain C++11 like :

```
    using namespace std;
    using namespace cv;

int main(){

    // Create a VideoCapture object and use camera to capture the video
    VideoCapture cap(0);

    // Check if camera opened successfully
    if(!cap.isOpened())
    {
        cout << "Error opening video stream" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Default resolution of the frame is obtained.The default resolution is system dependent.
    int frame_width = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    int frame_height = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);

    // Define the codec and create VideoWriter object.The output is stored in 'outcpp.avi' file.
    VideoWriter video("outcpp-.avi",CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'),10, Size(frame_width,frame_height));
    while(1)
    {
        Mat frame;

        // Capture frame-by-frame
        cap >> frame;

        // If the frame is empty, break immediately
        if (frame.empty())
            break;

        // Write the frame into the file 'outcpp.avi'
        video.write(frame);

        // Display the resulting frame
        imshow( "Frame", frame );

        // Press  ESC on keyboard to  exit
        char c = (char)waitKey(1);
        if( c == 27 )
            break;
    }

    // When everything done, release the video capture and write object
    cap.release();
    video.release();

    // Closes all the windows
    destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;
}
```

If it is working you have the same problem that we have :) QT has problem with the videowriter Opencv I assume.  Welcome to the club.

On the other hand did you find a solution ?