# Compressing a raw image buffer

Tags: c++, c, encoding, opencv, compression

I capture a raw image from a grayscale camera. When I transfer the image to OpenCV's IplImage and use `cvSaveImage("image.jpg",image)`, the image is saved with a size of around 160K. Whereas, if I use `fwrite` function in C to save the image buffer in `.pgm` format, the saved image size is 1.4M.

My question is:

Does `cvSaveImage()` compress the image into the specified format while saving? Actually, I am working on a smart camera with ARM platform and I want to avoid the overhead of cross-compiling OpenCV for ARM. How can I compress this image to `.jpg` without using `cvSaveImage`, but rather using C functions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/801054/1155650

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [Embedded JPEG](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mb-jpeg/) may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Or try the Independent JPEG Group source code.

http://www.ijg.org/