# openCV cvSaveImage() increases the size of image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, computer-science

i am loading an image and just saving the same image but with a different name using cvSaveImage(). After saving the size of the newly saved image gets increased. can anyone tell me why and how to avoid it?? here is my code:

int main(){

```
IplImage* src = cvLoadImage("test.jpg", 0);

cvSaveImage("reTest.jpg", src);

return 0;
```

}

thanks.

Comment: `jpg` is a compressed lossy format, so it isn't possible to decode and then encode again to get the exact same data.  The compression ration is variable, so it's possible that the original file was saved with a higher rate than what you're saving it with the second time.  I'd assume there are probably options in openCV to control this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different methods of compression and coding combined in JPEG.
Most likely your original image used a different compression/coding than standard openCV parametrization for cvSaveImage.

Try this:

```
IplImage* src = cvLoadImage("test.jpg", 0);
cvSaveImage("reTest.jpg", src);
IplImage* reSrc = cvLoadImage("reTest.jpg",0);
cvSaveImage("reTest2.jpg", reSrc);
```

if `reTest.jpg` and `reTest2.jpg` have the same size, openCV does not increase the filesize but just uses a different compression level or sth.
You would have to find out the compression level and coding of your original file and save it with these same parameters, maybe with a different library than openCV.

Answer (score 4):

It is because of low JPEG compression factor used by default in OpenCV. Here is how to to pass custom compression factor - [OpenCV cvSaveImage Jpeg Compression Factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801054/opencv-cvsaveimage-jpeg-compression-factor) .