# Open and save image in OpenCV makes image a lot larger (ruby-opencv)

Tags: ruby, opencv

I am using OpenCV in ruby with ruby-opencv (though I am suspecting that should not make a difference), and as a simple test, I open an image and save it with a different filename.

```
require 'opencv'

include OpenCV

image = CvMat.load("samples/CIMG0388.JPG")
image.save("samples/CIMG0388_2.JPG")
```

The result is that the saved image is a lot larger (318.3 Kb vs 187.0 Kb) though the dimensions are the same. Why is this? Does OpenCV add information to the resulting image? Or is it some default quality setting?

Comment: It is probably because `CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY` is set to 95. You might want to try out `cv::imwrite` and set the quality to something that you want. For further details, you can refer to http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite

Comment: Thanks, but the value of OpenCV::CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY is set to 1 in Ruby, unless this is some enum value. Is it?

Comment: Then I am guessing it is on a 0 to 1 scale; maybe you can try setting it to 0.95 or something..?

Comment: It may be an inverted calse (1 means don't compress, higher numbers reduce quality), and it is not 100% clear whether opencv supports controlling it. This question in 2009 suggested it was not supported back then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801054/opencv-cvsaveimage-jpeg-compression-factor

Comment: Ah, it turns out that it is just a key. This SO question helped me find the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801054/opencv-cvsaveimage-jpeg-compression-factor. By passing `{CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY => 20}` as the second parameter to the Ruby method, it took the quality value into consideration. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @scap3y, Kindly add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is as an answer:

It is probably because `CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY` is set to 95. You might want to try out cv::imwrite and set the quality to something that you want. For further details, you can refer to the [cv::imwrite documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite)..

Supplementary reading as added by @mydoghasworms : [OpenCV cvSaveImage Jpeg Compression Factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801054/opencv-cvsaveimage-jpeg-compression-factor)

Example solution in Ruby setting JPEG quality to 20:

```
require 'opencv'

include OpenCV

image = CvMat.load("samples/CIMG0388.JPG")
image.save("samples/CIMG0388_2.JPG", {CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY => 20})
```